# Is it possible to replace a word after a phrase using regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Input text: school of engineering, school of medicine

Output required: school of education, school of education

Rule: any words followed by 'school of' needs to be replaced by 'education'

```
$inputext = "school of engineering, school of medicine"; 
$rule ="//s/";
$replacetext = "education";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo($outputext);
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: well this is an invalid reges `//s/` as you have an unescaped delimiter in it.  `preg_replace('/(school of )[-a-z0-9_]+\b/i', '\1'.$replacetext, $inputext)`

Comment: `preg_replace("/\\bschool of .+?\\b/", "school of education", $inputext);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to capture anything or use lookarounds.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/uWZgW

```
$inputext = "school of engineering, school of medicine"; 
$rule ="/school of \K[a-z]+/";
$replacetext = "education";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo $outputext;
```

Match the preceding words (and space after `of`), restart the fullstring match with `\K`, then replace the target word.

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing, just use a **[positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** on `school of` plus the space:
`(?<=school of )\w+`

- `(?<=school of )` matches anything that comes after `school of` and a space.
- `\w` denotes any word character, and `+` denotes between one and an unlimited number.

So your code would be:

```
$inputext = "school of engineering, school of medicine"; 
$rule ="/(?<=school of )\w+/";
$replacetext = "education";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo($outputext);
```

Which outputs:

> school of education, school of education

This can be seen working on Regex101 **[here](https://regex101.com/r/oLjquO/1/)** and 3val **[here](https://3v4l.org/qOMVp)**.

Comment: True. I've removed that, simplifying the regex :)

Comment: I know i didn't ask this in the question. How can I tweet your code to look after, say Engineering school, Medical school -> Educational school?